# Be a Wordsmith — Assemble enough words to score 50 from the Triangular Settings

Tags: word, knowledge, no-computers, word-ladder

Use this triangular setting of letters to form as many words(minimum length 5) as possible, following the given rules.

You can start at any letter, follow the connected lines to pickup additional letters To form your final word.

You can do so multiple times, you can pickup single or more of the same in one stop, you can revisit the same letter as long as don’t stray from the connecting lines.

No plurals(Addition to already formed word), no past tense additions, no proper nouns, no hyphenation.

No archaic words. I let community be the judge of acceptance.

Scoring system..1 for 5, 2 for 6, 3 for 7 or more letters in the word.

Goal is to get the score of 50.
Whoever gets to 50 first will get the greencheck.

Some examples of words you can make:

Proof

Common

Moose

Foolproof

Here is the diagram of connecting triangles with letters . “O” in the center.

[image]

Comment: I think this might be too open to invite high quality responses. It's likely to result in incredibly long lists of words that satisfy the criteria.

Comment: @GordonK nope, the meticulous forming and arrangement of the letters have made it really hard...

Comment: Based on my work, 40 is easy..good wordsmith can reach 50+..if community wants to cap at certain score, I can do so

Comment: I am editing to make it 50 to expedite it.

Comment: Feel free to use my words..you can reach target faster..it is ok with me

Comment: Looks like people are allergic to “A”....I dont see a single word starting with A,...I suggest adding more words than necessary for insurance, in case somebody challenges your words..

Comment: Isn't this *exactly* the type of open-ended question that was disallowed [in our recent "The End Of Open-Ended Puzzles" post? What exactly counts as a word?

Comment: That’ why, I put limit to the total score count..is your question about word is philosophical or devious..I would let the puzzling community you define it for you

Comment: Edited the title to make it not open ended.

Comment: Anyone can make a Boggle "puzzle".  So this isn't a very good puzzle either way IMO.

Comment: I value honest feedback..biased feedback is sent todumpster

Comment: Honest feedback: open-ended Boggle puzzles aren't particularly good puzzles as we consider "puzzles."

Comment: Well taken.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

55 Points:
C:

> Cannon[2], Canoes[2], Canon[1], Commodes[3], Common[2], Commonest[3]

D:

> Decodes[3], Dollop[2]

F:

> Foods[1], Foolproof[3], Fools[1]

L:

> Loots[1]

M:

> Maces[1], Modes[1], Modest[2], Monocots[3], Moose[1], Moron[1], Morose[2], Mottoes[3]

P:

> Plodded[3], Plots[1], Prodded[3], Proforma[3], Proof[1]

R:

> Roman[1]

S:

> Sloop[1], Stood[1], Stool[1]

T:

> Tools[1], Toots[1]

Comment: 'commonest' uses N->E, which isn't allowed

Answer (score 2):

### Some of them (29 marks)

C:

> canoes[2], codes[1][from JonMark Perry, thanks!], colon[1][from JonMark Perry, thanks!], common[2][from Uvc]

F:

> foolproof[4][from Uvc], fools[1], frosts[2]

M:

> moats[1], modes[1], moose[1][from Uvc], moots[1], moron[1][from JonMark Perry, thanks!]

N:

> nodes[1]

P:

> pools[1], posed[1], proofs[2][from Uvc], proses[2]

S:

> stoops[2]["stoop" from JonMark Perry, thanks!], stools[2][from JonMark Perry, thanks!]

T:

> tools[1]

Comment: All acceptable.

Comment: @Uvc; what happened to the 'no plurals' rule (canoes, frosts, proses, modes)?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Uvc meant no canoe+canoes

Comment: You can have canoes as long as you don’t have canoe already..you cannot pad to the existing word

Answer (score 2):

**57 marks**

C:

> COLON(1), CODES(1), COOTS(1) COLTS(1), COEDS(1), COTTON(2), COOLS(1), COMMA(1)

D:

> DEACON(2), DONOR(1), DOORMAN(3)

F:

> FOOTSTOOL(3)

L:

> LOOTS(1), LOTTOS(2), LODES(1)

M:

> MORON(1), MANOR(1), MOROSEST(3), MOLLS(1)

O:

> OCEAN(1), ODDEST(2)

P:

> PLOTS(1), POOLS(1), PRODS(1), POOED(1), POSSESSED(3), POSSES(2), POMACES(3)

R:

> ROLLS(1), ROOTS(1), RODEOS(2)

S:

> STOOLS(2), STOOP(1), STORM(1), SLOTS(1)

T:

> TOSSED(2), TODOS(1), TOLLS(1)